# How to have base values in pillars that can be overridden?

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to store all Salt files (pillars, states, data files, etc.) in a git repository, so that this repository can be cloned on several different deployments.

Then I would like to be able to change the value of some pillar settings, such as a pathname, or a password, but without editing the original file which is in version control (i.e. those modifications would be local only and not necessarily versioned).

I would like to be able to pull new versions from the original repository (e.g. to add new pillar and state definitions) without losing the customized values.

E.g. the "base" or "default" pillar file would have settings like:

```
service:
  dir: /var/opt/myservice
  username: myuser
  password: mypassword
```

and I would like to customize some settings, in another file, without changing the base file:

```
service:
  dir: /mnt/data/myservice
  password: secret_password
```

The modified settings should take precedence over the base / default ones.

Is it possible to do this by using environments (e.g. a "base" environment and a "custom" environment)?

Or perhaps by including these custom pillar files?

The documentation seems to indicate that there isn't a fixed order for overriding pillar settings.

Comment: Check out the `import_yaml` statement in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32760671/425050. I've never tried this with `git_pillar` though.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that will do it because the overriding files would have to repeat the whole structure of the default file, and if new entries were added in the default file, they would have to be added to the override files as well. What I'm trying to achieve is to automatically import all keys from the default file, and only override select keys.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first suggest a way where you keep the original file and the customized settings in the git repository. See below how to override setting with a file outside of git.

**Setup Git Pillar**

I assume all files are stored in a git [pillar like described here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.git_pillar.html). I am using the syntax of salt version 2015.8 here.

```
ext_pillar:
  - git:
    - master https://gitserver/git-pillar.git:
      - env: base
```

In your top.sls file you can list different SLS files. They will override each other in the order listed in the top file:

```
# top.sls
base:
  '*':
     standard
  '*qa'
     qaservers
  'hostqa':
     hostqaconfig
```

This will apply on all servers:

```
# standard.sls
test:
  setting1: A
  setting2: B
```

This will apply on all servers with the name ending with 'qa':

```
# qaservers.sls
test:
  setting2: B2
```

This will apply to the server with the name 'hostqa':

```
# hostqa.sls:
test:
  setting1: A2
```

The commands `salt hostqa saltutil.refresh_pillar` and `salt hostqa pillar.data` will then show that the values A2 and B2 as they have all been merged together.

As this works without specifying environments, I suggest not to use environments here.

**Override some local settings outside of Git**

To override some of your settings locally, you can add another external pillar. One of the most simple ones is `cmd_yaml` that will run a command (here: `cat`) and merge the output with the current pillar:

```
ext_pillar:
  - git:
    - master https://gitserver/git-pillar.git:
      - env: base
  - cmd_yaml: cat /srv/salt/local_override.sls
```

All external pillars are executed in the order listed in the configuration file.